# prove $||x_k-x^*|| \leq \frac{s\delta}{1-q}+q^k||x_0-x^*||$ for $x_{k+1}=x_k-s(\nabla f(x_k)+ \epsilon_k)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the Gradient Descent Problem with bounded error, (for simplicity all $||.||$ refer to $||.||_2$

$x_{k+1}=x_k-s(\nabla f(x_k)+ \epsilon_k)$

where s is the constant step size (s>0),$\epsilon_k$ is the error term satisfying $||\epsilon_k|| \leq \delta$ for all k's and f in the positive quadratic function:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-x^*)^TQ(x-x^*)$

Let

$q=max(|1-s \lambda_{min}(Q)|,|1-s \lambda_{max}(Q)|)$

and assume that q<1. Show that for all k we have

$||x_k-x^*|| \leq \frac{s\delta}{1-q}+q^k||x_0-x^*||$

Honestly, very stuck on this question and not sure how to go about it.
Attempting to use @VHarisop's suggestions I obtained:

$x_{k+1}=x_k-s(\nabla f(x_k)+\epsilon_k) \  \ \ \ \  (1)$

$\nabla f(x_k)=Q(x_k-x^*)$ Plugging back into (1)

$x_{k+1}=x_k-s(Q(x_k-x^*)+\epsilon_k)$

$x_{k+1}-x^*=(I-sQ)(x_k-x^*)-s\epsilon_k$

$\ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = (I-sQ)((I-sQ)(x_{k-1}-x*)-s\epsilon_{k-1})-s\epsilon_k$

and so on and so forth.

$\ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = (I-sQ)^{k+1}(x_0-x^*)-s[\epsilon_k+\epsilon_{k-1}(I-sQ)...]$

Applying norm and convergence:

$||x_k-x^*||\leq \frac{s\delta}{1-q}+q^k||x_0-x^*||$

Comment: Hint: write down the formula for $x_k - x^*$ using $\nabla f(x_k) = Q(x_k - x^*)$ and try unfolding the recurrence.

Comment: @VHarisop do you mean to write out the formula for $||x_k-x^*||^2$ ?

Comment: No, what I wrote is correct. You can put norms on the expression in the very last step.

Comment: @VHarisop is this what you meant?

Comment: Not exactly. I meant $x_{k+1} - x_* = (I - sQ)(x_k - x^*) -s \epsilon_k$ using the update formula and $\nabla f(x_k) = Q(x_k - x^*)$. Then repeat for $x_k - x^*$ and so on.

Comment: @VHarisop so something more like this ?

Comment: Yes! That's basically all you need.

Comment: @VHarisop is this it or am i missing something ?